# Why WKWebView becomes nil?

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I use Swift4.0 and Xcode9.0. I try to show a website using `WKWebView`. It had no problem until yesterday, but today an error occurred.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WKWebViewViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    var startUrl = "https://www.apple.com"
    var requestUrl: String?

    override func loadView() {
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

        if let url = URL(string: startUrl) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)

        }

    }

}
```

The error occurs at `webView.uiDelegate = self`. Here's the error log:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

For debug, I added `print("webView:\(webView)")` under `loadView()`, and I found webView itself is `nil`.

I tried to add `?` to all `webView`, but only black screen appeared on the app.
Why `WkWebView` becomes nil? Is it some required setting outside my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *must* call `super.loadView()` when you override `loadView` this way. This is why the WKWebView is nil.

The docs suggest not overriding `loadView` at all when using a storyboard/xib

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method.

You should move those 2 lines of code as the second thing in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now `WKWebView` works! I totally forgot `super.loadview()`.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the delegates in the wrong method [loadView()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview). ViewController calls this method when its view property is needed and at this point all the IBOutlets are still nil.

You should move your code to a point where you are sure IBOutlets have been set like in `viewDidLoad` or better at `didSet` of the IBOutlet property

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView! {
  didSet {
      webView.uiDelegate = self
      webView.navigationDelegate = self
  }
}
```